# Programmatically add Site Users Web Part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I need to programmatically, using C#, add the SharePoint Web Part "Site Users" to a page.

I know how to add web parts but how do I get the "Site Users" web part from Share Point? I do not know how to instance it.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: if ( Homework ) return re-tag;

Comment: Why would you suspect this to be homework?

Comment: No, this is not homework. It is work. I found something called Members Web Part is this something like the "Site Users" Web Part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be the Members Web Part.

By simply setting "Display Type" to "WebUserGroups" the web part lists the groups and users on the site.

```
MembersWebPart membersWebPart = new MembersWebPart();
                membersWebPart.DisplayType = MembersWebPartDisplayType.WebUserGroups;
                membersWebPart.Title = "Användare och grupper";

                wpManager.AddWebPart(membersWebPart, "Right", 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was so hung up on the word "Users" that I overlooked "Members". :D